# Не получается сделать так что бы текст в kivy появлялся по символу ,а не весь сразу

Tags: python, kivy, label

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.clock import Clock



class MyBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, my_text, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(orientation="vertical", padding=10, spacing=10, **kwargs)
        self.letters = []
        for i in my_text:
            self.letters.append(i)
        self.label = Label()
        self.add_widget(self.label)
        self.a=0
        self.label.text= ""
        while self.a < len(self.letters):
            try:
                Clock.schedule_once(self.change_text, 0.1)
                self.a=self.a+1
            except:
                break

    def change_text(self,dt):
        try:

            self.label.text = self.label.text + self.letters[self.a]
        except:
            print(self.a)




class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        box = MyBox("пример текста")
        return box


app = MyApp()
app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    
from kivy.clock import Clock
    
class MyBox(BoxLayout):
        
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(orientation="vertical", padding=10, spacing=10, **kwargs)       
        self.label = Label()
        self.button = Button(text = 'Run')
        self.button.bind(on_release = self.run)
        self.text_input = TextInput()          
        self.add_widget(self.label)
        self.add_widget(self.text_input)
        self.add_widget(self.button)        
        
    def run(self, *args):
        self.label.text = ''
        self.start = Clock.schedule_interval(self.change_text, 0.2)
                            
    def change_text(self, instance, *args):
        my_text = self.text_input.text
        len_text = len(self.label.text)+1
        if len_text == len(my_text) or len(my_text) == 0:
            self.start.cancel()
            return
        self.label.text = f'{self.label.text}{my_text[len_text]}'
           
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        box = MyBox()
        return box  
    
app = MyApp()
app.run()
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).